# Continuous Integration for Open Source projects on Sourceforge

Tags: continuous-integration, sourceforge

I have a project hosted on Sourceforge.net using Mercurial.

Are there any free continuous integration services that can interface with open source projects and start a build every time there is a push to upstream?
I have had a great experience with **travic-ci.org** (github) and **drone.io** (bitbucket) but now need something similar that integrates with sourceforge.

As a workaround I have set up a proxy-project bitbucket->drone.io that pulls the repository from sourceforge and builds it... but that is not really what I had in mind.

(I do not actually own the hosted project, so switching to github/bitbucket is not an option right now.)

Comment: Unlikely (not impossible) until SF implement webhooks: https://sourceforge.net/p/allura/tickets/4542/

Answer (score 0):

That might be possible since March 11th, 2015.

See "[How to use webhooks for Git, Mercurial, and SVN repositories](http://sourceforge.net/blog/how-to-use-webhooks-for-git-mercurial-and-svn-repositories/)": SourceForge has introduced webhooks!

It comes with [webhook-management API](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Allura%20API/#webhook-management).

Comment: For this to work you would have to develop a proxy that receives the sourceforge webhook payload and then sends out a Travis CI webhook request, since both are custom formats.

Comment: @letmaik That is possible, indeed. I lost track of that feature since I wrote this answer 3 years ago.